# Check which process is using a given port

Tags: java, sockets, networking

I'm making a simple client-server application in Java. This is how I initialise the listening socket:

```
private void initSock() {
    try {
        sock = new ServerSocket(port);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.println("Could not listen on port: "+port+". Isn't the port already in use?");
        System.exit(1);
    }
}
```

That approach throws likely usefull error message when the port is used - however: Would it be possible to extend the info, like this:

> *Could not listen on port `xx`, it's being used by process `blahblah` with pid `xxx`.*

Will Java (and Windows, and eventually other systems) allow me to fetch that info?

I can find this info using command line, but that's really not what I want at this moment.

Comment: I suggest you just tell the user to run 'netstat' himself.

Comment: Which sounds like what I ask is impossible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not being able to fulfill your requirment, but below code can give you some more info:

```
public class NetStat 
{
    public static void main(String [] args) throws IOException
    {
        BufferedReader br= new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        System.out.println("Enter port number :");
        String port =br.readLine();
        StringBuffer output = new StringBuffer();
        Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("netstat -an");
        BufferedReader reader = 
                 new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));

        String line = "";           
        while ((line = reader.readLine())!= null) {
            if(line.contains(port))
            {
                output.append(line + "\n");
            }
        }

        System.out.println(output.toString());

    }
}


Input: 50773
Output: TCP    1xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:50773   xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8080    ESTABLISHED
```

Comment: But this one uses built-in system functions, doesn't it?

Comment: Yeah correct, now you have the whole content in string buffer. You can do any check and give the user appropiate message based on your check. Sorry for delayed response. :(

Comment: I hoped Java has it's own way, but I guess this will have to do.